# Does Nvidia Quadro 1000m support DisplayPort 1.2 - daisy chaining monitors doesn't work?

Tags: display, displayport, nvidia-quadro

I am trying to daisy-chain two Dell monitors (U2417H) and use them as external monitors on HP Elitebook 8560w laptop running Windows 10. The laptop's graphics is Nvidia Quadro 1000m.

I managed to make this work after enabling MST (Multi Stream Transport) option on the first monitor.

However, the monitors show the same screen, they seem to be in a Duplicate mode. I would like to used them in Extend mode.

The monitor User's Guide says that graphic card must support DisplayPort 1.2 with MST feature. Does Nvidia Quadro 1000m support this? If it didn't support 1.2, would it work at all? Not sure what to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The monitor User's Guide says that graphic card must support
>   DisplayPort 1.2 with MST feature. Does Nvidia Quadro 1000m support
>   this?

The Quadro 1000m only supports DisplayPort 1.1

[image]

Source: [Quadro Product Comparison](https://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/product-comparison/Product-Comparison-Quadro-mobile-series.pdf)

> If it didn't support 1.2, would it work at all?

Since your GPU does not support DisplayPort 1.2 what you want is not possible with the hardware you have.

Comment: Thanks. By asking "if it didn't support 1.2, would it work at all?" I ment would even the duplicate mode work; obviously it would, as it does work.

Comment: @Danijel - How am I supposed to know what you meant?  You asked if it would work, your question was about DisplayPort daisy-chaining and extend mode not duplication mode.